# $("#"+checkValue[i]).prop('checked', true) not working inJquery dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set dynamically checked attribute to the checkbox based on value, when i put alert the checkbox value that time only attribute is assigning, if i remove alert it's not showing checked attribute.

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
var objValue={};
         objValue= {
            ID:1,
         };
        $.post('response.php',objValue,function(response){
            var obj=$.parseJSON(response);
        checkValue=obj.sector_category_id.split(',');            
            alert(checkValue.length);
            for(i=0;i<=checkValue.length;i++){               
                if($("#"+checkValue[i]).val()==checkValue[i]){                    
                    $("#"+checkValue[i]).prop('checked', true);
                }
            }     
});
```

Comment: So that means you have a timing issue, so how is the code being called? Need more context top help you out.

Comment: @epascarello: i am calling inside the $( document ).ready(function()  function after ajax response success.

Comment: There is no document ready with ajax response.

Comment: @epascarello : updated my code now see..

Comment: How does your html looks like and how is checkValue looks like? It seems to me that you are comparing the id of the checkbox with it's value but I can't make sense of it If you don't describe it better.